# Getting error Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException when customizing urlManager component in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-components, yii-url-manager

I have set up the Yii 2 basic app and under `config/web.php` I use:

```
    urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ]
```

under `components`.

But when I try to run my application, I get the following error:

> Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException
>   Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::urlManager>

Same `urlManager` code works fine in advanced app though. Any ideas why?

Comment: work fine when i change the variable value enablePrettyUrl = true and showScriptName = false in vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\UrlManager.php

Comment: is you composer updated?

i have done this  
    'urlManager' => [
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
      'showScriptName' => false,
    ],

Comment: no composer updated. Just change the two variable in UrlManager.php

Answer (score 5):

```
Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::urlManager>
```

From this error message, it looks like that you are trying to redefine `urlManager` in the Application component which is not allowed.

`urlManager`, and several other components such as `security` are predefined as core application component. Most probably, redefining these core components will cause unexpected behavior (though I have not witnessed any).

Try removing the key `class` in the configuration.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is the correct configuration.

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        //'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>[
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: This looks like a repeat of Victors answer. Therefore as a standalone answer it does not add much value. Maybe as an edit to Victor's answer?

Comment: I also came to answer,but is not correct, then I resolved it and share the config. If you know yii configuration, you know these are two different answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this sequence**

```
'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'mailer'=>[
        'class'=>'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport'=> false,
        ],
        'authManager'=>
        [
            'class'=>'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles'=> ['guest'],
        ],
```